# style.css is not working of wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a child theme of WP-ocean but its style.css is not working, before I made the child theme of twenty nineteen and its working with its all functionality but same functions I have added for WP-ocean but its style sheet is not loading so I am doing inline styling. Below is my Function code.

```
<?php

add_theme_support('menus');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}



function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );


function my_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap4', 
'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'boot1','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', array( 'jquery' 
 ),'',true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 
 'boot2','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' 
),'',true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'boot3','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', 
array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );


function arphabet_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'My_Widgtet_Area',
    'id' => 'partner-slide',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init');

function prefix_add_content ($content){

return $content;
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'prefix_add_content');
```

Here is the style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Oceanwp Child
Theme URI: http://example.com/oceanwp-child/
Description: Oceanwp Child Theme
Author: John Doe
Author URI: http://example.com
Template: oceanwp
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, 
accessibility-ready
Text Domain: Oceanwp-Child
*/
@import
body{
color: #ff8b00!important;
}
```

Comment: Please provide ```style.css``` of your child theme

Comment: @Mulli i had added the style.css of my child theme, i had tried to change the body color of my theme but style.css is not working

Comment: Your ```@import``` line in ```style.css``` is wrong. Please look at https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/90-sample-child-theme for official oceanwp child theme. This may not solve the problem, but will clean errors.

Comment: To *solve* the problem please provide link to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow step:

1, The first create function add style.css

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_theme_file_uri('/style.css'));
}
```

2, In file style.css requirement

```
/*
Theme Name:     Theme Child Name
Template:       Parent theme
*/
```

Comment: i added this in my funtions.php and my style.css is working now  <?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_add_stylesheet' );
function my_plugin_add_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
}

Answer (score 0):

> body{
> color: #ff8b00!important;
> }

This is a style in your css file and not an inline style. Write your style in the HTML tag, then it is an inline style and has the highest priority.

I'm not familiar with Wordpress, but in such a case you can assume that Wordpress first loads your stylesheet file, and then overwrites your own file with the style from "twenty nineteen"

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a different theme astral theme and added this function in my functions.php and my style.css start working

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_add_stylesheet' );
function my_plugin_add_stylesheet() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, 
'1.0', 'all' );
}
```

Comment: Replacing a theme is not a solution to the problem, but a completely different path. Therefore, you cannot put it as an "answer". Please see my comments above if you wish to find a solution to the original problem

Comment: @Mulli sorry for not mentioning, my ocean-WP is also working as I added the above function in my functions,php. Actually I used a plugin in my code for a slider and there was no function for plugin in my code maybe that's why my stylesheet was not working anyway by adding the above function I got my problem solved.

Comment: By "style.css not working" - you mean that iits not included in the page html. Once you check that it does appear, you can verify that the appropriate css selectors do the job

Comment: @Mulli I think you are not getting my point, I made a child theme and added style.css but when i add code in theme body and then tried to style the theme by styling in style.css but my any style was not working actually style.css was not loading so finally I added the above function in my functions.php and my style.css started working and now I can style my theme. Hope you got my point thanks.